# I need helps multyple sites settings in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want run few sites in docker. 
I've run into a problem.

I have scheme 
site1
--api
--web

site2
--api
--web

site3
--api
--web

I have a docker-compose file

```
services:
 web_app1:
    container_name:site1
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/site1
      - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
  web_app2:
    container_name:site2
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "444:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/site2
      - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
  web_app3:
    container_name:site3
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "82:80"
      - "445:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/site3
      - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx

  php:
    container_name: php
    build: ./images/php
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/test
```

But it don't work

Comment: can you provide some more information about the problem you have been running into? do you get any error messages?

Comment: there are no errors. I'm trying to figure out how to run a 2.3 site in docker. to all through 80 port has been going

Answer (score 0):

The default port for Nginx docker image is 80 and not 443. Try to remove 443 mapping from your docker-compose.yml file

Or

If you want to run your container on 443, change the config in Nginx.conf from 80 to 443 and remove 80 port mapping from docker-compose file